# How do I use examples from someone else's book in my thesis (APA style 7th edition)?

Tags: thesis, plagiarism, citation-style

I am writing my first Linguistic thesis and am struggling with a question I can't find an answer to.
Since it is a Linguistic paper I need some word and abbreviation examples, which are provided by one of David Crystal's books.
The issue is that I don't really know how to use his examples without ending up plagiarising.
I read the APA style 7th edition so many times, searched the internet...I can't find a good solution, I hope my question is not stupid and I hope someone can help me.
Thank you :-)

Comment: Did you ask your supervisor?

Comment: Yes, my Professor told me to stick to the APA style 7th edition and now I don't feel like I can ask again.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the APA 7 style guide book?

Comment: APA has pretty clear guidance for how to cite information in-text as well as how to format and cite direct quotes. What are you trying to do that doesn't fall into either of these categories? Are you suggesting that you want to use a particular abbreviation/word throughout your paper?

Answer (score 1):

I won't speak to citation style, which is irrelevant for questions of plagiarism. But if you cite everything you use then you aren't plagiarizing. Plagiarizing is about attribution and by citing you avoid it.

However, you also have the problem of copyright if you are taking too much from a single source. And "too much" can mean both or either of *too many words* or *enough of the essence of a work that you lessen its value*.

If all or most of your examples come from one book, I think you need to worry about copyright. But if you draw from several sources you greatly lessen that risk, though you must cite everything, of course.

It is also possible to avoid copyright issues by getting an explicit license from the copyright holder, probably the publisher of the book, but possibly the author.